# One-point compactification is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $Y = X \cup \{\infty\}$ its one point compactification. The following is Munkres' proof that $Y$ is compact.

> Let $\mathscr{A}$ be an open covering of $Y$. The collection $\mathscr{A}$ must contain an open set of type $Y- C$  (where $C$ is compact in $X$), since none of the open sets contained in $X$ contain the point $\infty$. Take all the members of $\mathscr{A}$ different from $Y-C$ and intersect them with $X$; they form a collection of open sets in $X$ covering $C$. Because $C$ is compact, finitely many of them cover $C$; the corresponding finite collection of elements of $\mathscr{A}$ will, along with the element $Y - C$, cover all of $Y$.

I have two questions about his proof.

1. For each $U \in \mathscr{A} \setminus (Y-C)$ how do we know that each intersection $U \cap X$ belongs to $\mathscr{A}$, as is needed to obtain a subcover?
2. Why does it suffice to only consider one set of the type $Y - C$? What if $\mathscr{A}$ has uncountably many sets containing the point at infinity?

Comment: He is not saying the intersections with $X$ belong to the original open cover $\mathscr A$! Instead, those sets $U \cap X$ simply *are* an open cover of $C$ in their own right, so finitely many of them cover $C$. For those finitely many $U$’s (now ignore intersecting with $X$) use those together with $Y-C$ to get a finite cover of $Y$. The cardinality of $\mathscr A$ (countable or uncountable) plays no role at all.  Try drawing a picture, say with $X$ being a circle with one point removed, $Y$ being the whole circle, and $\infty$ being a label for the missing point.

Comment: @KCd Thank you I understand now. The key I was missing was that if $U \cap X$ is a cover of $C$  then $U$ is also a cover of $C$.

Comment: You meant $\{U_i \cap X\}$ and $\{U_i\}$, not $U \cap X$  and $U$ (which look like they are each just one set).

Comment: @KCd Yes that is correct, that was a typo. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding question 1**: The set $U \cap X$ does not necessarily belong to $\mathscr{A}$.

But you do not need it to belong to $\mathscr{A}$.

All you need is is to find finitely many $U$'s in $\mathscr{A}$, denote them $U_1,...,U_m$, such that $C \subset U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_m$, in other words such that $U_1,...,U_m$ cover $C$.

And the way you find those $U$'s is to apply compactness of $C$, like this. The set $\{U \cap C \mid U \in \mathscr A\}$ is an open cover of $C$ with respect to the subspace topology on $C$. By compactness of $C$ finitely many of those open sets form a cover of $C$:
$$C = (U_1 \cap C) \cup \cdots \cup (U_m \cap C)
$$
By elementary set theory, it follows that $C \subset U_1 \cup\cdots\cup U_m$.

**Regarding question 2:** Here's why it suffices to only consider one set of the type $Y-C$. You have already picked out $Y-C \in \mathscr A$ itself. And after that, you have already picked out finitely many elements of $\mathscr A$ that cover $C$, namely $U_1,...,U_m$. So now you just need finitely many more elements of $\mathscr A$ that cover everything in $Y$ BUT $C$. That is, you just need finitely many more elements of $\mathscr A$ that cover $Y-C$.

Hurray!! $Y-C$ is a single element of $\mathscr A$ that covers $Y-C$!!

Comment: I think I understand now. So because $\{U \cap C \mid U \in \mathscr A\}$ is an open cover of $C$ in $X$, it follows that $\{U \in \mathscr{A}\}$ is a cover of $C$ but in $Y$. And because of the compactness of $C$ we can find a finite subcover of $\{U \in \mathscr{A}\}$, which together with $Y - C$ is the finite subcover of $\mathscr{A}$ we are looking for. Is that right?

Comment: That sounds like a good way to put it.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!